# how to NOT modify htaccess run to different userDir in Cakephp

Tags: apache, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, mod-userdir

I have apache  userDir like http://127.0.0.1~/danny

so I modify the .htaccess   add   RewriteBase   /~danny/

It's work fine .

But I have many project , I often  copy code to different apache 
userDir

so I Frequent modify the .htaccess

I want to know how to like codeigniter

It's not  modify the .htaccess and run anywhere (different userDir  )

Any suggestions would be welcomed!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by modifying the `.htaccess` file which is located outside app folder.
Please try with this. I'm using this particular code and its working for me.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    Rewriterule ^your_dir/.*$ - [PT]
    RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`your_dir` Please replace with your directory name.

Now you'll be able to run a directory like this `http://example.com/your_dir`

Comment: thanks Vins replay ,
But I have one Project , It's often copy to different host
So I have 20+ host , I have to  Frequent modify the .htaccess

I don't want to hardcode my project , It manage my all code that is Hard

How to hardcode modifying the .htaccess , But It can deplay apache userDir ?